# Kotlin equivalent for extensions and reduce

Tags: swift, generics, kotlin, closures, combine

I am trying to port this class in swift to Kotlin. Is there a Kotlin way of achieving extensions and to reduce the state(get the state)

```
public final class MutateNode {
public var onSubscribe: (() -> Void)?
public var onPublish: ((State) -> Void)?
public var leafs: [Node]

public init(leafs: [Node], onSubscribe: (() -> Void)? = nil, onPublish: ((State) -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.leafs = leafs
    self.onPublish = onPublish
    self.onSubscribe = onSubscribe
}
}

extension MutateNode: ControlNode {
public var state: AnyPublisher<State, Never> {
    guard !leafs.isEmpty else {
        return Just(.failure)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return leafs.reduce(into: Just(.failure).eraseToAnyPublisher()) { (resultPublisher, nextChild) in
        resultPublisher = resultPublisher.flatMap { state in
            state == .success ? Just(state).eraseToAnyPublisher() : nextChild.state.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .handleEvents(
        receiveSubscription: { [weak self] _ in self?.onSubscribe?() },
        receiveOutput: { [weak self] state in self?.onPublish?(state) }
    )
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin does not support extending a class to retroactively add an interface. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861009/is-it-possible-to-add-an-interface-to-an-existing-class-in-kotlin) for example.

The Kotlin equivalent of Combine is [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html). It does include a [`reduce` operator](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/reduce.html).