# Is it possible to create an "extension class" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am currently working on a Kotlin project dealing with a lot of hardware, and I've been looking for a way to create something similar to an extension function, except with a class. In this case, I want a class to act as a subclass to another, but still be separated and in another package. Normally, I'd be using the class like so:

```kotlin
class Foo() {
    fun doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class Bar(val foo: Foo) {
    fun doSomethingWithFoo() {
        foo.doSomething()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val myFoo = Foo()
val myBar = Bar(myFoo)
myBar.doSomethingWithFoo()
```

Is it possible to make this code more readable by doing something one could do with an extension function?

```kotlin
// Is this possible?
val myFoo = Foo()
val myBar = myFoo.Bar()
myBar.doSomethingWithFoo()
```

I'm going with a wrapper extension function as an alternative for now, but I was wondering if this could be achieved directly.

```kotlin
// Wrapper function I'm using
fun Foo.Bar(): Bar {
    return Bar(this)
}
```

Comment: Related question with a similar use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861009/is-it-possible-to-add-an-interface-to-an-existing-class-in-kotlin/48861125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you're describing is a [delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html): a class which forwards all its methods (unless overridden) to an instance of a different class.

Kotlin has built-in support for this (unlike Java), but for it to work, both classes need to implement an interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun doSomething()
}

class Foo() : MyInterface {
    override fun doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

class Bar(val foo: MyInterface) : MyInterface by foo
```

That does pretty much the same as the code in the question, but without the boilerplate of manually specifying the forwarding of `doSomething()`.

The cunning part there is the innocent-looking `by foo`: it specifies that `Bar` is a delegate, implementing all the `MyInterface` methods by forwarding them to `foo`.  (Of course, you can add and override methods as needed — there would be little point in a delegate that behaved *exactly* like the object it was forwarding to!)

For more info, see the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look into it when I have more time, but this might actually be what I'm looking for.