# How to use extension methods in generic functions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, extension-methods

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to design an API for a binary serialization library. The idea is to provide some core serialization functionality within the library, while allowing users to easily extend it for their user types.

It looks like in contrast to some other languages, Kotlin doesn't allow for [implementing interfaces for existing classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861009/is-it-possible-to-add-an-interface-to-an-existing-class-in-kotlin). The related answer suggest to use extension functions as a work around. Trying to apply this approach in this use case leads to the following:

The core serialization library could implement some fundamental serialization (extension) functions for basic types like:

```kotlin
import java.io.DataOutputStream

fun Int.serialize(stream: DataOutputStream) { 
    // Some implementation...
}

fun String.serialize(stream: DataOutputStream) { 
    // Some implementation...
}

// Similar for other types...
```

Now users can implement serialization functionality for their user types based on these fundamentals. For instance:

```kotlin
data class CustomUserType(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
)

fun CustomUserType.serialize(stream: DataOutputStream) { 
    name.serialize(stream)
    age.serialize(stream)
}
```

So far so good.

Now the library should also offer functionality to serialize certain containers. For instance, if we have an `someArrayOfUsers: Array<CustomUserType>` it should be possible to write `someArrayOfUsers.serialize(stream)`. However, attempting to implement the corresponding generic function

```kotlin
fun <T> Array<T>.serialize(stream: DataOutputStream) {
    this.size.serialize(stream)
    for (element in this) {
        element.serialize(stream)
    }
}
```

doesn't compile, because Kotlin's type system is nominal and not structural, i.e., the compiler cannot know that `T` implements `T.serialize(stream: DataOutputStream)`. I assume that extension methods are more like overloading free-floating functions.

How would I solve this problem idiomatically in Kotlin? Is there a trick to tell the compiler about the extension methods of `T` in that generic function, or is it necessary to go for an entirely different approach involving some interface after all?

Comment: [Example on Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/cqFsOS0JU)

Comment: And here is [another example](https://pl.kotl.in/s1qcpeLTn) following the suggestion in the linked answer more closely. As explained in the code comment, it doesn't solve the problem as intended.

Comment: There’s no way to do this. Extension functions are not actually part of the class type and cannot fulfill interface contracts. @bluenote10 Your example is not compileable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I know, I'm searching for the most sensible work-around. I.e., how would an experienced Kotlin developer design an extensible serialization API?

Comment: If you look at the big serialization libraries for Java and Kotlin, they do it without type safety. It’s on the user to make sure classes have registered serializers for classes that aren’t handled automatically by the library. RuntimeException if you try to serialize something without a serializer. So there’s no workaround that has been found

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting for a while I came up with a solution. I'm not sure if it is particularly elegant, so I'm still curious to see alternatives.

Also, it is maybe not a general answer to using extension methods with generic functions. Trying to give the solution pattern a name, it may be a case of *dependency inversion*: The idea is to introduce a callback/closure mechanism instead of trying to model it directly with an interface.

---

On library side, the approach could look like:

```kotlin
typealias Encoder<T> = (T) -> Unit

class Serializer {
    
    fun serializeInt(x: Int) {
        // ...
    }

    fun serializeString(s: String) {
        // ...
    }

    // Similar for other types...
    // But also some generic versions:

    fun <T> serializeGeneric(x: T, encoder: Encoder<T>) {
        encoder(x)
    }
    
    fun <T> serializeArray(x: Array<T>, encoder: Encoder<T>) {
        serializeInt(x.size)
        for (element in x) {
            encoder(element)
        }
    }
}
```

Now users can implement an encoder for their types, which basically flips the role of the serializer vs `T`, i.e., instead of passing the serializer to a method of `T`, the serializer is captured in a closure, and `T` is passed to that function. For instance,

```kotlin
data class CustomUserType(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
)

// Multiple ways for a user to implement the encoder, either as companion object or just:
fun encoderCustomUserType(serializer: Serializer): Encoder<CustomUserType> {
    return { x: CustomUserType ->
        serializer.serializeString(x.name)
        serializer.serializeInt(x.age)
    }
}
```

Usage would look it:

```kotlin
val serializer = Serializer()

val user = CustomUserType("foo", 42)
serializer.serializeGeneric(user, encoderCustomUserType(serializer))
    
val users = arrayOf(user, user, user)
serializer.serializeArray(users, encoderCustomUserType(serializer))
```

As a result of having separated the "serialization interface" from `T` itself, this pattern probably always comes down to passing around pairs of `T` plus some generic helper type depending on `T`.